# Toggle linear fraction display in the header

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I think `$\frac{\partial \pi}{\partial w_i}$` looks better than `$\partial \pi / \partial w_i$`, but many journals don't agree. Is there any way that I can put a command in the header of my document to have my fractions display in linear form (with the solidus) for these aesthetically misguided journals without having to go through the text and adjust them? And ideally I could use this for all fractions, not just the derivative I give in the example.

Comment: Are we talking about fraction expressions that occur in inline math mode -- or about all fraction expressions, including those in display math mode?

Comment: What about consitently using an “abstract” command (_e.g._, `\pder`) for denoting partial derivatives, and changing its definition according to the journal you are submitting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to assess whether this may break other components within the document, but you could add

```
\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{#1 / #2}
```

to your preamble to perform a global replacement of `\frac` to the above format.

Note that you'll have to ensure you use parentheses around your arguments if they have multiple terms/factors.

Comment: I was going to add the remark contained in the last paragraph as a comment.  Doesn’t this make the whole idea practically useless?

Comment: @GuM: It depends on the extent to which `\frac` is used within the paper, I guess.

Comment: Instead of changing the definition of `\frac`, I’d rather define an “abstract” command for denoting partial derivatives…

Comment: @GuM You make a fair point, but I was actually hoping for a general answer for all fractions, not just derivatives. I do agree that the need for parentheses makes this only a partial (interesting) solution.

Comment: @Shane: It would be possible detect whether you've use some symbol within `#1` or `#2` and condition on adding parentheses. However, in some cases the symbol may be hidden (like `\newcommand{\multiply}{\times}` when one is searching for `\times` within the arguments), which would make a generalisation almost impossible. Apart from that, how would one guarantee that parentheses should be added in one case and not another?

Comment: @Werner I take your point--the infeasibility of generalization is an issue of my question, not your answer. I'm accepting your answer because it seems as close as I can plausibly get to an ideal solution.